# Function cannot find the value from a field in Maya Python UI

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I am building a Maya UI, for a script that I've been working on, but I am having a problem when I try to prevent multiple windows. Basically, if I don't place this in front of the code:

```
winID = 'vs-sfa'

if(cmds.window(winID, exists=True)):
    cmds.deleteUI(winID, window=True)
```

Everything works, but then the use could create a lot of windows and that would be problematic. When I add this code though, and try to access the value in a `textScrollList` field, I get `None`. Any suggestions? Here is the code..

```
winID = 'vs-sfa'
#Prevent multiple windows
if(cmds.window(winID, exists=True)):
    cmds.deleteUI(winID, window=True)

#Create new window 
window = cmds.window(winID, title="Create Sound from Animation", iconName='soundFromAnimW', widthHeight=(520, 400) )

#Tabs layout
tabs = cmds.tabLayout()
tab1 = cmds.columnLayout()

#Controls for the first tab
cmds.text(l='basic stuff')
cmds.setParent('..')
tab2 = cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )

#Controls for the second tab
cmds.text( label='Some text with instructions and stuff' )
cmds.button( label='Update Selection', command='updateSel()' )
cmds.button( label='Close', command=('cmds.deleteUI(\"' + window + '\", window=True)') )
cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, adjustableColumn=2, columnWidth2=[260,260] )
#The textScrollList fields, from which I get None
selection = cmds.textScrollList( numberOfRows=4, append=sel, allowMultiSelection=True, sc='updateAttrs()' )
freqs = cmds.textScrollList( numberOfRows=4, append=Cmaj )
cmds.setParent('..')
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
attrs = cmds.textScrollList(numberOfRows = 9, append=attrsList, allowMultiSelection=True)
cmds.button(l='Assign Frequency', command='assignFreq()')
connections = cmds.textScrollList( numberOfRows=4, allowMultiSelection=True)
cmds.button(l='Remove assignment', command='removeFreq()')
cmds.button(l='Create sound', command='createSound()')
messages = cmds.textScrollList(numberOfRows=6, allowMultiSelection=True)
cmds.setParent('..')
cmds.tabLayout(tabs, e=True, tl=((tab1, 'Basic'),(tab2, 'Advanced')))
cmds.showWindow( window )
```

Comment: Could you post a working example of your code (including your other functions `assigneFreq()` `removeFreq()`...) and give us more precisions on the error? There are multiple `textScrollList` in you UI, do the problem appear on every one of them?

Comment: Well you don't really need the other functions, since the error occurs with or without them being assigned to the fields.In any case though, @UKDP's answer is exactly what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code in Maya, I get the following error:

```
# Error: name 'sel' is not defined
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 26, in <module>
# NameError: name 'sel' is not defined #
```

When you're creating your `textScrollList` you try to append in it an object `sel` which is not defined and do not exists yet.

The reason why it is working when you remove the two first lines to delete the window if it exists is probably because you create the `sel` variable further in the script and, when you recreate a new window the variable is now defined and can populate the newly created `textScrollList`.

What you could do is either creating the variable `sel` before calling it in your window or create your `textScrollList` empty and then, when you define the `sel` variable, edit the field and append the variable in it.